# Can i edit locked sentence in feed filters status change?

Tags: case, chatter-feed, casefeed, feed-based-layout

[![.][1]][1]

This is way I can see when case update, I need to see the the thing that updated in this line. But to see that I have to click the drop down arrow in the left side

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get your question.  Whereas your title indicates a question regarding editing locked items, your text seems to be about the lack of instant visibility of the thing that updates something. What have I missed?!

Comment: Instead of this line "Case status updated", Can I have the title of the thing that got updated? Currently the updated thing is visible when i click the arrow head in left side. I want to see it directly